# Mergsort using pointers rather than indices?

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, mergesort

So I need to write a *Merge Sort* algorithm where,

> pointers should be used rather than array indexes to access array elements during the sort, so the method takes 2 `int` pointers, `high` and `low`, and works from there.

### Question:

Is it possible to sort the array without indexing it, or does the args should be pointers as opposed to values?

P.S.: Very unfamiliar with pointer operation so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since an array is a contiguous block of memory, you can use pointers to access array members much the same as with an index:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *pointer = array;
int x = *(pointer + 1);
// x = 2
```

The compiler automatically calculates the offset based on the size of the data:  `sizeof(int)`.

So for your project, if you are given a pointer to the first and last elements of the array, You can split the array in the middle:

```
int *middle = firstPointer + ((lastPointer - firstPointer) / 2);
```

Then you can keep doing this recursively

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort use sequential access for input from each of two runs (part of an array) and output to a single run (part of the output array). You can use local pointers that you advance by 1 instead of indexing from base pointers. So the main merge process would look something like this:

```
    int * plft = left;           // ptr to left run
    int * prgt = right;          // ptr to right run
    int * pdst = destination;    // ptr to output
    // loop with checks for reaching end of either left or right run
        if(*plft <= *prgt)       // at some point in the merge function
            *pdst++ = *plft++;
        else
            *pdst++ = *prgt++;
```

The question doesn't mention if the goal is to implement a top down (use recursion to fill stack with pointers to runs until run size == 1, then start merging and returning) or a bottom up merge sort (skip the recursion step, initialized run size to 1, merge pairs of runs across array until all pairs merged, then run size *= 2, and repeat until run size >= array size).

The wiki article shows simple examples of both top down and bottom up merge sort.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort